# Upload music to iPhone/iPod/... directly without iTunes

Tags: c++, c, itunes, itunes-sdk

is it possible to program a tool that sends music to iPhone/iPod without putting the songs in iTunes?

the tool can work with "iTunes SDK" andit is not attended to go against Apple rules

the idea is to not "cache" the songs as iTunes in libraryes, just upload it directly to the iPhone/iPod from file server this help if have music library and you do o not want to have a local copy just to use it with iPhone/iPod!

is there way to achieve that?

I hope my Idea is clear, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to achieve that - a player called MediaMonkey does that. I seem to remember that still requires iTunes to be installed on the machine, but you never need to add your tracks to iTunes after installing it.

As to *how* it's done - that I don't know, but the MediaMonkey guys might be willing to share.

Answer (score 1):

[**Floola**](http://www.floola.com) looks like what you want.  It supports music, videos, podcasts and smart playlists, and runs on Windows, Mac or Linux.  It will also convert files as required.

Alternatively, if you have a fileserver running Linux then [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) may already be installed, or will be easy to install.

EDIT: If neither of those suit, there is a roundup of iTunes alternatives here:  [Managing iPod Without iTunes](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/191-managing-ipod-without-itunes)